# Change document.ready function to normal function without messing brackets

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, brackets

I don't want my xmlhttp-request to be executed on runtime, how can I place it correctly in a function, so next I can trigger the request by calling the function?

My xmlhttp-request is :

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$.post('domain', {Key1: test, Key2: "testing"}, function(data){
console.log(data);
var jsonobject = data;
$('#Box').val(JSON.stringify(data));
console.log(jsonobject);

localStorage.setItem('test', JSON.stringify(jsonobject));

})

});
```

Thank you!

Comment: What bit about putting it inside a function and calling it are you having problems with?

Answer (score 0):

just put it in a normal function: Put anything in param if you have dependency like variable,obj

```
function apiCall(/*param*/){
  $.post('domain', {Key1: test, Key2: "testing"}, function(data){
    console.log(data);
    var jsonobject = data;
    $('#Box').val(JSON.stringify(data));
    console.log(jsonobject);
    localStorage.setItem('test', JSON.stringify(jsonobject));
 }) 
}
```

Then call the function apiCall() when you needed.